# Getting "500 - Internal server error" html response as an error from WCF SOAP service while upload and downloading files from/to remote server

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF SOAP service written in C# and .net Framework 4.7 and hosted on on-premises IIS web server.
Service perform file Upload and Download from WPF client to network drive.

I am getting "500 - Internal server error" html response as an error. not always but most of the times i am getting this error. after couple of attempt or after restarting client machine, tried again and it worked.

Since long time we haven't made any code changes to this service but form last 2 to 3 months, we are facing this issues.

[Error Log from WPF client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCCLW.png)
[WPF client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8VZE.png)

1. enabled SVC trace log to monitor the Activity but did not find any activity for this Service when failed.
2. checked event logs. could not find any thing.
3. checked web.config file for bindings, Max file size limits etc.

Comment: Make the wcf tracing and message logging work. Also you may check the network and resource usage of the client-side and server-side.